# PHP String Replace From Array of Values

Tags: php

I have several strings that will be replaced with the same string...

ie

```
 $text=str_ireplace('[/VIDEO]','</div>',$text);
 $text=str_ireplace('[/ARTICLE]','</div>',$text);
 $text=str_ireplace('[/IMG]','</div>',$text);
```

anyway to use an array in lieu of the initial string value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. See the documentation for [`str_ireplace`](http://php.net/str_ireplace):

> If search and replace are arrays, then str_ireplace() takes a value from each array and uses them to do search and replace on subject. If replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values. If search is an array and replace is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of search.

```
$text=str_ireplace(array('[/VIDEO]', '[/ARTICLE]', '[/IMG]'),'</div>',$text);
```

Comment: got it, I swear I tried it with no success, but works now.. of course. 
thanks.

Comment: yup that would do it. If it is not working problem is somewhere else.